# Inaccurate but useful name on an old question

Tags: discussion, title

A [question which I have an answer on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe-using-python-del) seems to have become the canonical resource for doing a particular thing. (In this case, deleting a column from a DataFrame in a Python package called Pandas.)

But the original question was not actually *about* that. It was something quite specific about a why a particular method of deleting a column didn't work.

But the OP named the question rather inaccurately as

> Delete column from pandas dataframe

which, over the years, led many people (around 700,000 at time of writing) to the page looking for how to delete a column.

A few weeks ago a low-rep user edited the title to more accurately reflect the original post. But it is now confusing as a resource for people who just want to know how to delete a column!

Should I revert the edit?

Comment: Heh... I've been wondering the same about [this question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari), in which my answer simply points out a typo, but is nevertheless treated as the canonical answer to the question title.

Comment: @BoltClock Funny case :D. But it looks like the other answers could answer the general question. (I'm no mobile dev, so I can't tell for sure)

Comment: I would prefer a title which matches the actual question. If it doesn't work that good as a sign post anymore, then you could create a new question with the more general title and close it as a dupe of the original question with your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general I'd be very concerned to edit title of popular question. While I'd like title to reflect the question in many cases it is the misunderstanding covered in title that actually makes question popular and hence useful. If I would be changing title significantly I'd consider creating explicit duplicate to provide original hints to search engines (old title plus cleaned up body similar to original question).

In this particular case I would reject the change as not useful while it was still suggestion - I don't see how it made question more clear - python is already added as tag (plus presumably implied for "pandas") and `del` sounds like obvious way to delete something:

> Delete column from pandas DataFrame 
>   Delete column from pandas DataFrame using python del

On other hand I don't think change will hurt searching for this question, so since it is approved already it can as well stay.